# How do I disable mouse acceleration for my mouse but keep in enabled for my touchpad?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, 15.10

as the questions says I want to disable mouse acceleration for my mouse, but keep it for my touchpad. I use a fresh install of Ubuntu 15.10 with unity. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

There are several utilities for playing with mouse acceleration (for example, `xset m` changes all connected devices and `xinput --set-ptr-feedback <device>` changes a specific device; see the `xset` and `xinput` man pages for further details), but these settings will be lost on reboot.

A more permanent solution would be to create a new file in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` called something like `60-mouse-no-accel.conf` with the following content

```
# Remove acceleration from actual mice (but not touchpads, etc)

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Disable mouse acceleration"
    MatchIsPointer "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"

    # Set mouse acceleration.  Defaults to 2/1 4
    # Query using xset q | grep -A 1 Pointer
    # Set using xset m 2/1 4
    #  or using xinput --set-ptr-feedback <device> 4 2 1
    # Set acceleration to zero to disable
    Option "AccelerationNumerator" "0"
    Option "AccelerationDenominator" "1"
    Option "AccelerationThreshold" "4"
EndSection
```

Comment: This worked just a little. First of all a tricky part is to identify my mouse. I now use:
`MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Logitech_G500_343767B2CD0018-mouse"`

Comment: Thank you for your help. This worked just a little. First of all a tricky part is to identify my mouse. I now use:
`MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Logitech_G500_343767B2CD0018-mouse"`

But: This just works on the login screen. Once I have logged in, the acceleration gets restetted. So I guess the must be a hidden config in Unity. :(

Anyway, I have added a File to `~/.config/autostart` witch resets the acceleration via `xinput`. That's not a nice way, but I guess it works.