# The solution for disabling mouse accel in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS across reboots does not work for me

Tags: mouse

[How to disable mouse acceleration in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/794185/how-to-disable-mouse-acceleration-in-ubuntu-16-04/794420)

I tried every solution in this post and they didn't work across reboots.  The 'xset m 0/1 4' command works but when I create the 50-mouse-accel-disable.conf, 80-mouse-accel-disable.conf, or 90-mouse-accel-disable.conf files they all don't work across reboots.  I even tried it with 'Identifier "My Mouse"' and 'Identifier "12"' since my zowie mouse is listed as ID 12 when i do 'xinput list' command:

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ E-Signal USB Gaming Keyboard              id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SteelSeries SteelSeries Siberia 800       id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Kingsis Peripherals ZOWIE Gaming mouse    id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ E-Signal USB Gaming Keyboard              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make your settings consistent after reboot/shutdown is to add the command `xset m 0/1 4` to "Startup Applications" in the Dash. The command will be run when you log in.