# Disable Mouse Acceleration In Ubuntu Unity 18.04 LTS?

Tags: unity, mouse

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.  After installation, I disabled mouse acceleration with gnome tweaks (Flat Mouse)

I later installed Unity and the mouse acceleration settings reverted. I'd like to know how to disable mouse acceleration using Unity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable mouse acceleration in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/794185/how-to-disable-mouse-acceleration-in-ubuntu-16-04).  Also https://askubuntu.com/questions/698961/disable-mouse-acceleration-in-ubuntu-15-10

Comment: alright, so i disabled mouse accel using this method: http://www.webupd8.org/2016/08/how-to-completely-disable-mouse.html                       Though how do i higher my sensitivity? Now it suddenly got really low.